# Trouble Displaying Tube Geometry in Three.js

Tags: javascript, three.js

I'm new to Three.js and I'm having trouble getting a tube to show up on the screen. I'm using a basic material to keep the lighting simple, but it's not working. Can someone help me figure out why it's not appearing?

```
const scene = new THREE.Scene()

var points = []
for (var i = 0; i<5; i++){
    points.push(new THREE.Vector3(0,0,2.5*(i/4)))
}
var   = new THREE.CatmullRomCurve3(points)

var tubeGeometry = new THREE.TubeGeometry(curve, 70, 10, 50, false);

var tubeMaterial = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({ color: 0xff0000 });
console.log(tubeMaterial)

// Create a mesh based on tubeGeometry and tubeMaterial
var tube = new THREE.Mesh(tubeGeometry, tubeMaterial);
console.log(tube)
// Add the tube into the scene
scene.add(tube);

/**
 * Sizes
 */
const sizes = {
    width: window.innerWidth,
    height: window.innerHeight
}

var light = new THREE.HemisphereLight( 0xffffbb, 0x887979, 0.9);
scene.add( light );

const camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(75, sizes.width / sizes.height)
camera.position.set(0, 0, 10);
scene.add(camera)

/**
 * Renderer
 */
const renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({
    canvas: canvas
})

renderer.setSize(sizes.width, sizes.height)
renderer.setClearColor(0x8FBCD4);

renderer.render(scene, camera)
```

Initially I was trying with a texture on the standard material but I switched to basic material for simplification.

Answer (score 0):

You have couple of issues in your code:

1.You didn't create `canvas` element:

```
const canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
document.body.appendChild(canvas);
```

2.You have typo:

```
var   = new THREE.CatmullRomCurve3(points)
```

3.You wrongly creating geometry on `TubeGeometry`, try this one:

```
const points = [];

for (let i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
  points.push(new THREE.Vector3(0, 0, 2.5 * (i / 4)));
}
const curve = new THREE.CatmullRomCurve3(points);

const tubeRadius = 0.5;
const radiusSegments = 10;
const closed = true;

const tubeGeometry = new THREE.TubeGeometry(
  curve,
  70,
  tubeRadius,
  radiusSegments,
  closed
);

const tubeMaterial = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({ color: 0xff0000 });

const tube = new THREE.Mesh(tubeGeometry, tubeMaterial);

tube.rotation.x = 2;
tube.position.y = 1;

scene.add(tube);
```

4.Debbuging, etc.

If I were you, I would install `OrbitControls` or `GUI`, then you will get easier life with debbuging, etc.

**npm install lil-gui**

```
import { OrbitControls } from 'three/addons/controls/OrbitControls.js';
import GUI from 'lil-gui'
```